# Proof: $2x \bmod 3 \neq 0$ if $x \bmod 3 \neq 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not very fluent in mathematical proofs. High School has, sadly, not taught me any kind of proof-theory. That's why I would like your help with my proof of

$$2x \bmod 3 \neq 0$$

given that $$x \bmod 3 \neq 0$$

Actually it seems absolutely logical for me, but I have no idea how to tackle the modulo for proofing. $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be more comprehensive: $x \mod 3 \neq 0 \Rightarrow x = 3k +q$  $(0 < q < 3)$ so we know $2x = 2(3k+q) = 6k+2q$. If we can show that 3 does not divide $2q$, then $2x \mod 3 \neq 0$. We know that $q$ equals $1$ or $2$ from our previous statement of $x$. If it equaled $1$ then $2q$ equals $2$. If it equaled $2$ then $2q$ equals $4$.

Comment: No idea, sorry. Accepted it again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show the contrapositive, that if $$2x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$ then $$x \equiv 0 \pmod 3.$$ This is a special case of the fact that for any prime $p$, if
$ab \equiv 0 \pmod p$ then either $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $b \equiv 0 \pmod p$.  (Which is another way of saying that if $p | ab$ then either $p | a$ or $p |b$.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the TeX in your answer. Congruence (in elementary number theory) is gotten with '\equiv'. The symbol you used '\cong' means congruence in geometry.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=1\mod 3$, then $2x=2\mod 3$.

If $x=2\mod 3$, then $2x=4=1\mod 3$.

In both cases, this is not equal to $0\mod 3$.

Comment: Thank you @Rasmus. What I still don't get is why this proves it. Is there a like a rule in module calculation I am not aware of?

Comment: @scro: This proves the statement since any integer must be congruent to either $0, 1$, or $2\bmod{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ mod\ 3\!:\  \ 0\: \equiv\: 2\:x\ \Rightarrow\  0\: \equiv\: 2\:(2\:x)\:  \equiv\: x\:.\: $ Alternatively, $\rm\ 0\: \equiv\: 2\:x\:\equiv\: -x\ \Rightarrow\ x\:\equiv\:0\:.$

More generally, if $\rm\ ab = 1\ $ then $\rm\ b\:x = 0\ \iff\ x = 0\ $ follows by scaling both sides by $\rm\:a\:,\:$ i.e. scaling an equation by a unit (invertible) element yields an equivalent equation. In the above case note that $\rm\:2\:$ is a unit (invertible) since $\rm\: mod\ 3\!:\ 2\cdot 2 \equiv 1,\ \ or\ \ 2\:\equiv -1\:.$